# How to compare previous and current rows in Google Bigquery?

Tags: google-bigquery

My sample table scenario is as follows:

```
+-------------------------------+
| User | Time        | Property |
|------|-------------|----------| 
| u1   | 2020-02-01  |    p1    |
| u1   | 2020-02-02  |    p1    |
| u1   | 2020-02-03  |    p2    |
| u1   | 2020-02-04  |    p2    |
| u2   | 2020-02-01  |    p2    |
| u2   | 2020-02-02  |    p2    |
| u2   | 2020-02-04  |    p1    |
| u2   | 2020-02-05  |    p1    |
+-------------------------------+
```

The data is ordered by `User` and `Time` columns.

I want to add a column as follows

```
+--------------------------------------------+
| User | Time        | Property | New_Column |
|------|-------------|----------|------------|
| u1   | 2020-02-01  |    p1    |  1         |
| u1   | 2020-02-02  |    p1    |  1         |
| u1   | 2020-02-03  |    p2    |  2         |
| u1   | 2020-02-04  |    p2    |  2         |
| u2   | 2020-02-01  |    p2    |  3         |
| u2   | 2020-02-02  |    p2    |  3         |
| u2   | 2020-02-04  |    p1    |  4         |
| u2   | 2020-02-05  |    p1    |  4         |
+--------------------------------------------+
```

The value in the `New_Column` is unique for a sequence of continuous rows until the `User` or the `Property` changes.

---

Edit 1:

I am trying to build a logic that makes use of the previous property in time for a user.

```
select 
  *
, lag(property,1) over (partition by User order by Time) as Prev_Property
from table
order by User, Time
```

Next I added a column `Row_Number`
This gives me

```
+------------------------------------------------------------+
| User | Time        | Property | Prev_Property | Row_Number |
|------|-------------|----------|---------------|------------|
| u1   | 2020-02-01  |    p1    |  Null         | 1          |
| u1   | 2020-02-02  |    p1    |  p1           | 2          |
| u1   | 2020-02-03  |    p2    |  p1           | 3          |
| u1   | 2020-02-04  |    p2    |  p2           | 4          |
| u2   | 2020-02-01  |    p2    |  Null         | 5          |
| u2   | 2020-02-02  |    p2    |  p2           | 6          |
| u2   | 2020-02-04  |    p1    |  p2           | 7          |
| u2   | 2020-02-05  |    p1    |  p1           | 8          |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I tried to build a logic as follows

```
CASE
  WHEN Prev_Property is not null
  THEN Row_Number
  WHEN Property <> Prev_Property
  THEN Row_Number
  WHEN Property = Prev_Property
  THEN   -- a logic that gives me the Row_Number of the Prev_Property
```

I am still trying to build the final few conditions in my query. This is my attempt so far.

I don't need the values in `New_Column` to be in order. I only want them to be unique and satisfying the grouping criteria.

Comment: Have you came up with any Query?

Comment: Hey, I edited my question and added my attempt so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * EXCEPT(flag),
  COUNTIF(flag) OVER(ORDER BY User, Time) New_Column 
FROM (
  SELECT *, 
    (User, Property) != LAG((User, Property)) OVER(ORDER BY User, Time) flag
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
)
```

You can test, play with above using dummy data from your question as in example below

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'u1' User, DATE '2020-02-01' Time, 'p1' Property UNION ALL
  SELECT 'u1', '2020-02-02', 'p1' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'u1', '2020-02-03', 'p2' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'u1', '2020-02-04', 'p2' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'u2', '2020-02-01', 'p2' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'u2', '2020-02-02', 'p2' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'u2', '2020-02-04', 'p1' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'u2', '2020-02-05', 'p1' 
)
SELECT * EXCEPT(flag),
  COUNTIF(flag) OVER(ORDER BY User, Time) New_Column 
FROM (
  SELECT *, 
    (User, Property) != LAG((User, Property)) OVER(ORDER BY User, Time) flag
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
)
-- ORDER BY User, Time
```

with output

```
Row User    Time        Property    New_Column   
1   u1      2020-02-01  p1          0    
2   u1      2020-02-02  p1          0    
3   u1      2020-02-03  p2          1    
4   u1      2020-02-04  p2          1    
5   u2      2020-02-01  p2          2    
6   u2      2020-02-02  p2          2    
7   u2      2020-02-04  p1          3    
8   u2      2020-02-05  p1          3
```